# Dynamically adding Textarea with ckeditor 5

Tags: php, html, ckeditor5

I have created a jquery to add dynamically new textarea with ckeditor 5. Editor works fine but the problem is when saving data to DB. It shows empty data. Only the first editor has a data and the other has empty data

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success" id="rowAdder"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</a>
<div class="fieldGroup">
<textarea class="form-control" name="containment_action[]" id="editor" placeholder="">
</div>
<div id="fieldGroupTemplate" style="display:none">
<textarea class="form-control" name="containment_action[]" id="editor" placeholder="">
</div>

$("#rowAdder").click(function() {
        var numGroups = $('.fieldGroup').length;

        if (numGroups < maxGroup) {

        // create new section from template
        var $fieldHTML = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'row fieldGroup border-top pt-5',
        'html': $("#fieldGroupTemplate").html()
        });

        // insert new group after last one
        $('.fieldGroup:last').after($fieldHTML);

        // instantiate ckeditor on new textarea
        $fieldHTML.find('textarea').ckeditor();

        } else {
        alert('Maximum ' + maxGroup + ' sections are allowed.');
        }
        

    });
```

Comment: you have to share code

Comment: share your code (don't forget data saving methods)

Comment: Coincidentally, I have just integrated this functionality to my website. Before sending the data to the database, you have to show the content of the variable in which the editor is collected. either with var_dump an alert or whatever, depending on how you add the data to the database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 textarea with the same id because it will give you an error because it will always take the value of the first element with that id. You must have two different ids and a script to create the ckeditor for each one

For the same reason, if you have 2 texareas, I do not recommend that you search for them by the type of element but by the id, which is why they must have two different ids